# Find differences between a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, diff

I need to get a difference between multiple dictionaries inside a list. What I have:

```
[{'WWW': '1.1.1.1', 'Dom': '1.1.1.1', 'SPF': None, 'MX': '1.1.1.1', 'PTR': 'reverse.dom.com'}, 
 {'WWW': '1.1.1.1', 'Dom': '1.1.1.1', 'SPF': None, 'MX': '1.1.1.1', 'PTR': 'reverse.dom.com'}, 
 {'WWW': '2.2.2.2', 'Dom': '2.2.2.2', 'SPF': None, 'MX': '2.2.2.2', 'PTR': 'reverse.dom.com'}, 
 {'WWW': '1.1.1.1', 'Dom': '1.1.1.1', 'SPF': None, 'MX': '1.1.1.1', 'PTR': 'reverse.dom.com'}]
```

But I need extract from that dict, just something like:

```
list 2: [('WWW', '2.2.2.2'), ('Dom', '2.2.2.2'), ('MX', '2.2.2.2')]
```

Just the diferences between all dicts. Just for context, that is because I need to know if there is a miss configuration between multiple DNS zones.

So, how can I do that?

Comment: what is the underlying reason for the question? what are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a list of domains, so I need to get dns info about: mx, a, ptr, spf against multiple dns (local and external, like Google and OpenDNS) and search for diferences. So, I build a script to query all DNS I want and put in the dictionary above, but now I need to compare all and find what is different.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the dictionary values are hashable, use `itertools.chain` and [`collections.Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

```
>>> lst = [{'WWW': '1.1.1.1', 'Dom': '1.1.1.1', 'SPF': None, 'MX': '1.1.1.1', 'PTR': 'reverse.dom.com'}, 
...  {'WWW': '1.1.1.1', 'Dom': '1.1.1.1', 'SPF': None, 'MX': '1.1.1.1', 'PTR': 'reverse.dom.com'}, 
...  {'WWW': '2.2.2.2', 'Dom': '2.2.2.2', 'SPF': None, 'MX': '2.2.2.2', 'PTR': 'reverse.dom.com'}, 
...  {'WWW': '1.1.1.1', 'Dom': '1.1.1.1', 'SPF': None, 'MX': '1.1.1.1', 'PTR': 'reverse.dom.com'}]
>>> c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(d.items() for d in lst))
>>> print([key for key,val in c.items() if val == 1])
[('WWW', '2.2.2.2'), ('MX', '2.2.2.2'), ('Dom', '2.2.2.2')]
```

Comment: I just also need the list index, because that will say if the diff is in DNS 1, 2 or 3...

Comment: @user2217329 -- Are you sure that only one of the dictionaries will be different?  what if `lst[0]` has a different `WWW` but `lst[2]` has a different `Dom`?

Comment: Good point! Then I need to show both, like: (0,'WWW','5.1.1.1') and (2,'Dom', 2.2.2.2').

Comment: And what if half of your list says one thing for `WWW` and the other half says something else?  Which is right?

Comment: There is no right or wrong. If all lists have differences, that should show all of them, so that I can fix the DNS misconfigurations.

The best cenario is no diff, because I need local and external DNS running on the same configuration, but there is some cases thats not true.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

data = [{'WWW': '1.1.1.1', 'Dom': '1.1.1.1', 'SPF': None, 'MX': '1.1.1.1', 'PTR': 'reverse.dom.com'}, 
        {'WWW': '1.1.1.1', 'Dom': '1.1.1.1', 'SPF': None, 'MX': '1.1.1.1', 'PTR': 'reverse.dom.com'}, 
        {'WWW': '2.2.2.2', 'Dom': '2.2.2.2', 'SPF': None, 'MX': '2.2.2.2', 'PTR': 'reverse.dom.com'}, 
        {'WWW': '1.1.1.1', 'Dom': '1.1.1.1', 'SPF': None, 'MX': '1.1.1.1', 'PTR': 'reverse.dom.com'}]

unique = [key for key, cnt in
              Counter(p for d in data for p in d.items()).items() if cnt == 1]
```

Result:

```
>>> unique
[('WWW', '2.2.2.2'), ('MX', '2.2.2.2'), ('Dom', '2.2.2.2')]
```

And then to get the index of the list (in this case `idx` would be `2`):

```
idx = next(i for i, d in enumerate(data) if d.get(unique[0][0]) == unique[0][1])
```

Comment: Thanks for quickly reply! That's almost what I need. But, if I have a little change: 


    `data = [{'WWW': '1.1.1.1', 'Dom': '1.1.1.1', 'SPF': None, 'MX': '1.1.1.1', 'PTR': 'reverse.dom.com'}, 
             {'WWW': '2.2.2.2', 'Dom': '2.2.2.2', 'SPF': None, 'MX': '2.2.2.2', 'PTR': 'reverse.dom.com'}, 
             {'WWW': '1.1.1.1', 'Dom': '1.1.1.1', 'SPF': None, 'MX': '1.1.1.1', 'PTR': 'reverse222.dom.com'}]`


like change only one values of one different dict, this should get me: 


    `dict 2: [(...)] 
     dict 3: [(...)]`